# How to fix JS and Jquery not working for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm setting up a chrome extension and have the settings menu built, the CSS and HTML work fine. I'm using this button on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/paularce/pen/oLqqOZ) and it says my code has no errors [image: No errors] How do I define the function? I have now downloaded [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js) to the folder and called it using script as seen here[image: files & code] using the CDN didn't work because of some security restrictions for developing an extension.

```js
$('button.cooldown').click(function(){
  var btn = $(this);
  btn.prop('disabled', true);
  setTimeout(function(){
    btn.prop('disabled', false);
  },15000);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient( 72.5deg,  rgba(0,175,255,1) 27.9%, rgba(0,224,254,1) 84.2% );
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
}

#header {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #393e46;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}




.button {
background-color: rgb(80, 220, 100);
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 5px;
}

.button:hover {
background-color: #393e46;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 5px;
}

.button_cancel {
background-color: #f44444;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 5px;
}

.button_cancel:hover {
background-color: #393e46;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 5px;
}




/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

  input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=file], select {
padding-left: 15%;
}

.form-item {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wallpaper-title {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
}












button.cooldown {
  background: #336699;
  min-height: 48px;
  min-width: 144px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.cooldown:active, button.cooldown:focus {
  outline: none;
}
button.cooldown:disabled {
  background: #264d73;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
button.cooldown:disabled:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: #1a334d;
  animation: cooldown 15s linear;
}
@keyframes cooldown {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
/* layout stuff */
section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #333;
}
p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home+</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
  <script src="popup.js"></script>



  <div id="header">
    <h2>Home+</h2>
    <h6>Settings</h6>
  </div>

</head>

<body>


  <!-- The settings pane, expand at will -->
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
    <form class="settings">
      <div class="form-item">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
        <div class="form-item">
          <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-item">
        <label class="container">Show Weather
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </div>



      <div class="form-item">
          <button class="cooldown">Refresh Weather</button>
      </div>



      <div class="form-item">
        <label for="hompagebg" class="wallpaper-title">Upload Wallpaper</label>
        <center>
          <input type="file" id="hompage-background" name="hompagebg" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" size="20">
        </center>
      </div>


      <div class="form-item">
        <button type="button" class="button">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="button_cancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You haven't imported jQuery (or whatever defines `$`).

Comment: If you go into your pen settings you'll see that you have added **jQuery** as an external JavaScript library, the extension doesn't seem to have this library.

Comment: inspire yourself from this `i am using react here` try to have the same thing using jquery and webpack : https://github.com/azizgharbi/Google-Chrome-extension-starter

Comment: I downloaded [https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js]  to my extension folder and called it on the popup.HTML file using <script src="jquery.3.4.1.min.js"></script> but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CodePen you linked has [jQuery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js) as an external library, you can check it on the CodePen page under Settings on the JavaScript page.

To make your extension work, include jQuery into the extension.

A working example, where I added `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the HTML before including `popup.js`:

```js
$(() => {
    $('button.cooldown').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
      btn.prop('disabled', false);
    },15000);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient( 72.5deg,  rgba(0,175,255,1) 27.9%, rgba(0,224,254,1) 84.2% );
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
}

#header {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #393e46;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}




.button {
background-color: rgb(80, 220, 100);
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 5px;
}

.button:hover {
background-color: #393e46;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 5px;
}

.button_cancel {
background-color: #f44444;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 5px;
}

.button_cancel:hover {
background-color: #393e46;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 5px;
}




/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

  input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=file], select {
padding-left: 15%;
}

.form-item {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wallpaper-title {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
}












button.cooldown {
  background: #336699;
  min-height: 48px;
  min-width: 144px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.cooldown:active, button.cooldown:focus {
  outline: none;
}
button.cooldown:disabled {
  background: #264d73;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
button.cooldown:disabled:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: #1a334d;
  animation: cooldown 15s linear;
}
@keyframes cooldown {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
/* layout stuff */
section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #333;
}
p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home+</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>



  <div id="header">
    <h2>Home+</h2>
    <h6>Settings</h6>
  </div>

</head>

<body>


  <!-- The settings pane, expand at will -->
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
    <form class="settings">
      <div class="form-item">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
        <div class="form-item">
          <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-item">
        <label class="container">Show Weather
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </div>



      <div class="form-item">
          <button class="cooldown">Refresh Weather</button>
      </div>



      <div class="form-item">
        <label for="hompagebg" class="wallpaper-title">Upload Wallpaper</label>
        <center>
          <input type="file" id="hompage-background" name="hompagebg" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" size="20">
        </center>
      </div>


      <div class="form-item">
        <button type="button" class="button">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="button_cancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I get this error: Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: is there a way to download jquery directly and link it using < script >? Also, where do I download it from?

Comment: Yes, just download it, and put the file next to popup.js, then include it in the html in a script tag above popup.js.

Also you have to use the code from the above example in `popup.js`

Comment: FYI, you would have to add https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com to your extensions manifest file in the permissions section to avoid that CSP error.   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Comment: @ap.dev  I tried that and still got the samesite=secure error, everything was linked correctly

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. I needed to add                               
 $(document).ready(function () {
});                                                                                                                             to my popup.js and download jquery to my files and call it using script